# Format code listing package

Tags: formatting, listings, code, scripts

I am documenting a script which has almost 43+ keywords. The output I want is something on the below lines...
[image]

and the latex code I have is

```
\documentclass[a4paper, onesided]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{customc}
{%
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
commentstyle=\color{green!40!black},
stringstyle=\color{red!40!black},
columns=fullflexible
}%

\lstdefinelanguage{InnoScript}{%
keywords={AllowCancelDuringInstall, WindowVisible, RestartIfNeededByRun, Name, MessagesFile, Source, DestDir, Flags, Languages, Parameters, Filename, WorkingDir},
sensitive=true,
comment=[l]{;},
string=[b]'
}%
\begin{document}
\lstset{style=customc}
\lstinputlisting[language=InnoScript, firstline=39, lastline=51]{<WindowsLocation>Script.iss}
\end{document}
```

The errors I receive is:

[image]

Where am I wrong?

**EDIT**

@Daniel, came to rescue. Now, the question arises. How do I fix the overfull box warning? :-D

Comment: Load one of the available color packages (e.g., `\usepackage{xcolor}`), which define the `\color` command.

Comment: And, by the way: Welcome to tex.se :-)

Comment: What the...? Someone willing to blind me in one eye? I have been kicking myself inside out!!!Thank you so much @Daniel.

Comment: About the overfull box, `breaklines=true` added to the 'lstdefinestyle`?

Comment: Geez. Another foot-in-mouth moment...
@TorbjørnT. thank you so much

Comment: @manucpp Adding `breaklines` to your custom style will most likely get rid of the overfull-box warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `\usepackage{color}` line to your preamble, like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
```

this works for me on Mac using latest TeXShop and TeXLive.